# selfestruct() in soldity

Tags: solidity, contract-development, selfdestruct

Hey I'm trying to use selfdestruct in solidity but I'm getting this error when I'm trying to run selfdestruct(address*) :

> TypeError: Invalid type for argument in function call. Invalid
> implicit conversion from int_const 0 to address payable requested. -->
> contracts/Hello_World.sol:9:22: | 9 | selfdestruct(0x0); | ^^^

*address- my Ethereum address

The code :

```
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0; 
contract HelloWorld { 
string public message; 
function setMessage(string memory newMessage) public { 
message = newMessage; 
} 

function remove() public {
 selfdestruct(0x0); 
} 
}
```

Comment: Can you post more code? That error doesn't sound like it's related to `selfdestruct`.

Comment: Hi MicahTaylor! Welcome to Ethereum Stackexchange! It is better to edit your own question to add a code, since in the comments it is not formatted and hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you're passing a constant integer to `selfdestruct`, while the correct call would be to pass an address. `0x0` is not the 0 address, it's just the hexadecimal form of the integer 0. You need to convert it into a payable address and pass it to `selfdestruct` as follows:

```
selfdestruct(payable(0x0))
```

Actually, you don't even need to use the hex format and you could just use the decimal format as follows:

```
selfdestruct(payable(0))
```

Note: casting as `payable` only works in Solidity versions >=0.6.0.

By the way, what this call does is burn any ETH contained in that contract upon destruction. Make sure that this is what you want to do.